# C Client/Server Communicating with fprintf?

Tags: c, sockets, client, printf

How would you make a server be able to send messages to a client using printf or fprintf instead of using the write system call?

I already have my server made and working, sending messages via write, but I would rather use fprintf.

For example this didn't work:

```
newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
FILE *fp = fdopen(newsockfd, "w");
fprintf(fp, "test"); 
fflush(fp);
```

I know have a new problem. When I have just the above code it works and I can see it in my browser, however if I add read(newsockfd,buffer,255) after then I on longer see the message posted in my client.

Comment: I think you're just missing the `fflush(fp);`...

Comment: gracias sir, you are very wise.

Answer (score 2):

The functions that work on `FILE`s are very unlikely to do what you expect them to do when working on sockets, and are more than likely to mess things up for you. If you want to implement formatting, I'd suggest you roll your own formatting functions to write to the sockets: all you need to do is create a variadic function, call `vsprintf` to the formatting and send the result over with `write` or `send`...

Comment: I don't see what problem you're envisioning. The one major issue is with blocking IO. Using `stdio` with non-blocking mode is not possible; it will result in unrecoverable errors on the `FILE`. Therefore I would recommend against using stdio with sockets unless either (1) you only have one connection you're dealing with and no asynchronous events, or (2) you're using threads and don't care if you block.

Comment: @R. I read that as using `write/send` to send data formatted with `vsprintf`... not sure where the disagreement is :p

Answer (score 0):

How bout using a dup system call, so redirect the stdout to socket descriptor.. so I think you can put your stuff in socket using printf.